# scraping simple page: scrapy doesn't return all links

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl the following page using scrapy: http://www.t13.cl/home/d_ultimas/10. I use

```
class T13(CrawlSpider):
    name = 't13'
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.t13.cl"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.t13.cl/home/d_ultimas/10']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'.')),
             callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        pass
```

but it only returns one link (the first one). Why doesn't it follow all the `<a>` links in that page? (if I use the shell, it does return all the selectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your requests are being filtered by the `allowed_domains`. Change it to:

```
allowed_domains = ["t13.cl"]
```